# change initial GPS configuration with API?

Tags: android, gps, supl

moin-moin,

i want to change (in ICS) some of the values inside the /system/etc/gps.conf file to get better values while in northern germany, to speed up the startup of locationManager/locationProvider.

Is it possible (without rooting the device) to read/set these values with the android API programmaticaly, even temporally for my application?

**Edith:** f.e. from etc/gps/gpsconfig.xml

```
- <job id="Assisted_Cold_Starts">
  - <task repeat="1000000">
    <startup ignore_rom_alm="true" ignore_ram_alm="true" /> 
  - <asst>
    - <!-- pos Lat="-30.0" Lon="-50.0" Alt="50" /--> 
      <pos Lat="33.7691" Lon="-84.4062" Alt="300" /> 
    - <!-- pos Lat="37.0" Lon="-122.0" Alt="50" /--> 
    - <!-- pos Lat="37.26533652" Lon="-121.94128855" Alt="51.4" /--> 
    </asst>
    <req_pos_single acc="50" timeout="30" /> 
    </task>
  </job>
```

and from /etc/gps.conf:

```
NTP_SERVER=tw.pool.ntp.org
XTRA_SERVER_1=http://xtra1.gpsonextra.net/xtra.bin
XTRA_SERVER_2=http://xtra2.gpsonextra.net/xtra.bin
XTRA_SERVER_3=http://xtra3.gpsonextra.net/xtra.bin
SUPL_HOST=http://207.114.133.116
SUPL_PORT=59910
```

want to change this to

```
NTP_SERVER=de.pool.npt.org
SUPL_HOST=supl.google.com
SUPL_PORT=7276
```

Comment: What are "some of the values"? You definitely cannot access `/system/etc/gps.conf` from the SDK on a non-rooted device. It is conceivable, though very unlikely, that there are ways of manipulating "some of the values", but we can only tell you that if you tell us what "some of the values" are.

Comment: I am reasonably certain none of that is modifiable on unrooted devices, unless it is somehow supported via `sendExtraCommand()`.

Comment: I seriously doubt you will ever be able to produce even a small improvement in gps performance by making these changes.

Comment: thanks you two. Just for curiosity: if these values are of no help, why are they there? The initial position is on the other side of the world, so completeley useless to derive any information from it?